# How do I read specific characters of filename in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, filenames

Lets say I have a bunch of folders/files with a name like

```
    abc_06082018
```

where the numbers are the date it was created but they are different for each folder, however the abc_ stays the same for every name.
How do I only read after the abc_ and up until 8 number in?

BTW: The folder is the current working directory of the python 2.7 program, so i'm using os.getcwd() and saving it to a variable most likely as a string. The idea is to get the date from the cwd and make a file in the cwd in the form of

```
    newfile_06082018.txt
```

where the numbers are taken from the name of the cwd
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the folder is in a string - just use normal string manipulation! `.partition()` is your friend.

```
folder = os.getcwd()

absolute_folder = os.path.abspath(folder)
only_folder_name = os.path.basename(absolute_folder)

prefix, sep, date_suffix = only_folder_name.partition('_')
filename = 'newfile_{date}.txt'.format(date=date_suffix)
```